# Error in Create Event

Tags: mysql, events

Error

Hi, I am facing following error while creating event

SQL query:

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS BackupTest ON SCHEDULE EVERY1WEEK DO BEGIN CALL TEST(
'test'
);

END
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EVENT IF NOT EXISTS BackupTest
>       ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK
>       DO
>         BEGI' at line 1

Please help.

Comment: IF  NOT EXISTS is not used in that manner...

Comment: @apomene `IF NOT EXISTS` is fine here. See the [syntax reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html)

Answer (score 0):

You're using the compound statement syntax so you need to change the delimiter before your `CREATE` statement or MySQL will stop at the first semi-colon. Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS BackupTest ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK DO BEGIN CALL TEST(
'test'
);

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```